# App works in development but Error H10 after deployment

Tags: python, heroku

I deployed my app to heroku and i get H10 error log when I run the `heroku logs --tail` command.
The error log:

```
2020-11-21T12:40:27.833034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=uploaq.herokuapp.com request_id=d8563da4-4cfc-43d6-ad04-cb95d8fe3047 fwd="197.210.227.20" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-21T12:40:28.019331+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=uploaq.herokuapp.com request_id=c5a1a84d-3c79-4857-ab38-9f15a16b12da fwd="197.210.54.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-21T12:40:28.428222+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=uploaq.herokuapp.com request_id=be4ba73e-ebf4-40ac-b6a2-3c07516ae9e0 fwd="197.210.55.57" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was my procfile

```
    web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi:app
```

And since i am deploying from a windows pc. i had to create a procfile.windows file and put the code

```
    web: python wsgi.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```